# What is the difference between Fish tuna and Fish tuna = new Fish() in Java

Tags: java, object

The question is pretty self-explanatory. My question is what is the difference when I declare an object using

```
Fish tuna = new Fish()
```

rather than

```
Fish tuna
```

Also, when should I use the first one and when should I use the second one?

Comment: Depends if you're inside a method or not... although to be pedantic: they're both syntax errors because there's no `;`

Answer (score 2):

```
Fish tuna = new Fish()
```

You just declared and initialized at that point of time.

`Fish tuna`

You just declared and left the initialization part to later codes.

`Fish tuna`, have chances to initialize on demand. Means when ever you want to initialize either in a constructor, or in a method later.

Just matter of requirement and usage.